# Region from points

Tags: regions

Is there a built-in way to define a 3D region from an arbitrary list of points. The points will represent vertices of the edges of the region and we can assume that 1) they are not all on the same plane and 2) that there are at least 4 points. The points should define the region that allow the biggest volume given the provided vertices. I imagine something like `Polygon` except for 3 dimensional regions.

It needs to be a  Mathematica region - something that I could use with functions like `RegionIntersection` or `Volume`. I have provided a list of example points below along with a (crude) picture of the volume I would like to derive from them, which I made manually. I am not necessarily interested in this volume in particular (it is just an example). I am mainly wondering if there is a generic method for any set of points

```
 points = {{0, 0, 1}, {5, 0, 0}, {1, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {4, 3, 0}, 
           {5, 0, 2}, {1, 3, 2}, {4, 3, 2}}
```

[image: VolumePicture]

Comment: You can create a region for arbitrary 3D points with `DelaunayMesh` and/or `MeshRegion` . Unfortunately, `RegionIntersection` does not work with 3D `MeshRegion` objects. (This is mentioned in the section "Possible Issues" for `RegionIntersection`.) This command finds the volume of the 3D region over the points in the question: `RegionMeasure[DelaunayMesh[points]]`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov do you know any way to extract part from `DelaunayMesh@points`? The `FullForm[DelaunayMesh@points]` shows a lot of information but I can't extract any thing like I do with  `Graphics3D`. Thank you

Comment: @Algohi You can use `MeshCells` and `MeshCoordinates`. For example, look into the output of  `MeshCells[DelaunayMesh[points], 2]` .

Comment: @AntonAntonov I know `MeshCells` and thank you for that but what I meant is when you look at `FullForm[DelaunayMesh@points]` I want for example to get the first list inside `MeshRegion` (`Cases[DelaunayMesh@points,MeshRegion[x_,__]:>x])` or what is insde `Tetrahedron` (`Cases[DelaunayMesh@points,MeshRegion[_,x_,__]:>x])` and so on. I can't use these methods because `MeshRegion` is Atomic expression and I cannot find a way to do that.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks you. Do you know if the 3-dimensional mesh primitives from a `DelaunayMesh` are guaranteed to be a set of Mathematica regions? For example, I was able to do `RegionUnion @ MeshPrimitives[DelaunayMesh[points], 3]` for this example, but I didn't know if this would be a solution in every case. Can you think of a case where this would not work?

Comment: It seems that @BenP1192 asks not about mesh regions, but about regular regions. Am I right? If not, why not to use `ToBoundaryMesh ` and `ToElementMesh ` functions?  They solve exactly such a task.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I think you are right  -- the question is not about mesh regions. That is why I posted a comment not an answer (talking about creating MeshRegion objects from points).

Comment: @BenP1192 I was not able to get a region with the command `RegionUnion@MeshPrimitives[DelaunayMesh[points], 3]` using the points defined in the question.

Answer (score 12):

```
points = {{0, 0, 1}, {5, 0, 0}, {1, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {4, 3, 0}, {5, 
    0, 2}, {1, 3, 2}, {4, 3, 2}};

reg = ConvexHullMesh @ points
```

[image]

```
RegionDimension @ reg
```

> 3

```
Volume @ reg
 (* or *)
RegionMeasure @ reg
```

> 21.5

```
p1 = {2.6161, 2.60692, 0.880247};
RegionMember[reg, p1]
```

> True

```
p2 = {0.915295, 0.507214, 0.367796};
RegionMember[reg, p2]
```

> False

```
RegionCentroid @ reg
```

> {2.61628, 1.44767, 1.08721}

```
Integrate[x y z, {x, y, z} ∈ reg]
```

> 82.0625

---

`RegionIntersection`, `RegionUnion` etc. all have in their documentation (under *Possible Issues*) that they are "not implemented for `MeshRegion` objects embedded in 3D" and "nor for `BoundaryMeshRegion` objects embdedded in 3D". My idea is to triangulate the `MeshRegion` into `Tetrahedron`s and `RegionUnion` them into the desired `Region`:

```
tri = TriangulateMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity];
pts = MeshCoordinates @ tri;
ord = Cases[Show[tri][[1]], Tetrahedron[x_] :> x, Infinity] // First;
tetra = Tetrahedron /@ (pts[[##]] & /@ ord);
Volume /@ tetra // Total
```

> 21.5

The volume agrees.

```
r = RegionUnion[tetra];
RegionPlot3D @ r
```

[image]

```
Volume @ r
```

> 21.4583

The volume slightly diverges from the correct value. Nevertheless:

```
ball = Ball[{0, 0, 1}];
RegionPlot3D @ (int = RegionIntersection[r, ball])
```

[image]

```
Volume @ DiscretizeRegion @ int
```

> 0.530894

---

I want to check how accurate is the volume measurement of `int`.

I start with altered points:

```
points1 = {{0, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}, {1, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {4, 3, 0}, {5, 
    0, 2}, {1, 3, 2}, {4, 3, 2}};
```

where I changed the first point - `{0, 0, 1}` - to `{0, 0, 0}`. Next I played with it forcefully

```
{b1, t1} = GatherBy[points1, Last];
ord = Drop[#, -1] & /@ (Flatten[#, 1] & /@ 
      FindCurvePath /@ {b1, t1}) // First;
```

to create the correct ordering for making

```
hex = Hexahedron @ Join[b1[[ord]], t1[[ord]]];
```

which has

```
Volume @ hex
```

> 24

I then take manually

```
b2 = {{1, 3, 0}, {5, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
```

for creating the chunk additially added to the above `hex`:

```
tetra = Tetrahedron @ b2;
```

These two can be handled with

```
Volume @ (region = RegionDifference[hex, tetra]) // N
```

> 21.5

to create the initial region of interest. Because this is a `Region`, one can

```
ball = Ball[{0, 0, 1}];
RegionPlot3D[#, PlotPoints -> 100]& @ (inter = RegionIntersection[region, ball])
```

[image]

(and do other `Region*` functions on it).

```
Volume @ N @ inter
```

> 0.534992

So the two measurements of the volume agree with each other.