# Is it OK that SameQ considers expressions identical, although they have different structure?

Tags: evaluation, sparse-arrays, expression-test

```
$Version
(* 10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015) *)

Information[SameQ]
(* lhs===rhs yields True if the expression 
      lhs is identical to rhs, and yields False otherwise.  >> *)

a = SparseArray[Automatic, {1}, 0, {1, {{0, 0}, {}}, {}}] &;

b = With[{s = SparseArray[Automatic, {1}, 0, {1, {{0, 0}, {}}, {}}]}, s &];

SameQ[a, b]
(* True *)

Depth /@ {a, b}
(* {6, 3} *)

LeafCount /@ {a, b}
(* {14, 2} *)

Position[a, _]
(* {{0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, 
    {1, 4, 0}, {1, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 2, 0}, {1, 4, 2, 1, 0}, {1, 4, 2, 1, 1}, 
    {1, 4, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 4, 2, 1}, {1, 4, 2, 2, 0}, {1, 4, 2, 2}, 
    {1, 4, 2}, {1, 4, 3, 0}, {1, 4, 3}, {1, 4}, {1}, {}} *)

Position[b, _]
(* {{0}, {1}, {}} *)
```

Is it expected behavior? Are the expressions stored in variables `a` and `b` identical?

---

*Update:* I found function `` System`Private`VerbatimSameQ `` that appears to check if two expressions are really completely identical.

Comment: Have you looked at `FullForm /@ {a, b}`?  In case `a`,  `SparseArray` has not evaluated, but in case `b`, it has and become atomic, which affects `Depth` and `LeafCount`, but not the `FullForm` (nor, therefore, `SameQ`).

Comment: `FullForm`s look character-wise identical, `StandardForm`s look different. `TreeForm`s are also slightly different.

Comment: `Hash`es are the same.

Comment: I noticed before that `SameQ` will give true for two arrays that differ in whether they are packed or not,  `Needs["Developer`"];
ara = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}];
ara2 = FromPackedArray[ara];
{PackedArrayQ /@ {ara, ara2},
SameQ[ara, ara2]}`.  They do end up having the same `FullForm` and `Hash`, but they aren't perfectly the same under the hood.

Comment: I also noticed that `Uncompress[Compress[b]]` does not round-trip `b` exactly, but rather converts it to the same form as `a`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 At least in 10.1.0 that function is *not* a solution.

Comment: Vladimir, I notice that you have not Accepted an answer to this question.  Do you find mine lacking?  Is there something I can do to extend, correct, or clarify it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need not turn to anything as complicated as `SparseArray` to see the same behavior.

```
a = Rational[1, 2] &
b = With[{s = Rational[1, 2]}, s &]

  (*  Rational[1, 2] &  *)

  (*  1/2 &             *)

a === b

  (*  True              *)
```

*Structurally* these are equivalent, but in one case the structure is unevaluated and in the other it is the external representation of an atomic internal format.

I learned to doubt "sameness" from the answers to my Stack Overflow question:

- [Instability in DeleteDuplicates and Tally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6166895/618728)

As WReach wrote: **SameQ Is *Not* An Equivalence Relation**

A more trustworthy comparator is [`Order`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Order.html).

```
Order[a, b]

  (*  -1              *)
```

The function `` System`Private`VerbatimSameQ `` that you discovered is *not* a solution, at least in version 10.1.0.  Instead it appears to just be `SameQ` with a [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete.html) attribute.  Evaluating `a` and `b` gives the same "True" result as `SameQ`:

```
System`Private`VerbatimSameQ @@ {a, b}

System`Private`VerbatimSameQ[##] &[a, b]

  (*  True              *)

  (*  True              *)
```

Comment: Interestingly, applying `FullForm[]` on both `a` and `b` shows them to be both `Function[Rational[1, 2]]`, so I wonder if the display is a different issue altogether.

Comment: @J.M. I fear I don't understand the point you are making.  As I said they are structurally identical.  One is atomic however and the other is not. `AtomQ[Rational[1, 2]]` vs `AtomQ[Unevaluated@Rational[1, 2]]`.

Comment: It was less a point and more a question of sorts; now that you mention that `AtomQ[Unevaluated @ Rational[1, 2]]` is `False`, I'm now actually confused as to why the `Unevaluated[]` makes a difference, even after using `Trace[]` to see how things work. (This also happens with `Complex[]`, apparently.)

Comment: @J.M. I terribly fear I am "teaching grandmother to suck eggs" but: it is impossible to enter atomic expressions directly in plain code: `Rational[1, 2]` must *evaluate* before it becomes atomic; until then it is just an arbitrary head with two leaves.  (I know `AtomQ[Unevaluated[1]]` is an exception to that statement but I think *numeric entry forms* are a special case, cf `HoldComplete[1*^6]`.)

Comment: I see; so my *gedanken Mathematica* was faulty in that respect. Thanks, and I had better update! :D

Comment: @J.M. Great, now you can take over the world. ;^)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `SparseArray`s are "atomic". Mathematica is getting more and more atomic expressions with each version. There are good reasons for this (mostly performance), but it can also get problematic because there are many operations which need to be *defined* (i.e. what makes sense) and *implemented* separately for each kind of atomic expression.  Sometimes this implementation is done in a not fully consistent way. The discrepancy between `SameQ` and `Depth` is one example.

I think that finding the best way to handle each atomic expression is not at all an easy task.  `SparseArray` has certain behaviours only because it represents an array, for which operations like e.g `Length` make sense. Thus enacting general rules, like "every atomic expression has `Length` 0" would be counterproductive.  Some inconsistency is probably unavoidable.

What complicates matters more is that many complex atomic objects do have a compound expression representation, which will usually immediately eveluate to the atomic version.  These representations are typically used for serialization—writing to text files (`Save`), sending through MathLink, `Compress`ing, etc. See [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96604/12) on how to get this representation reliably.  How visible these representations are during normal use varies. Some will show up with a simple `InputForm`.

In principle, there can be a disconnect between *what an expression represents conceptually*, what its compound form looks like, and what its true internal representation is.  In practice, there probably is a disconnect between them.  For example, think about `Graph`s.  It isn't even obvious when two graphs are conceptually *the same*.  Should that mean isomorphism?  Should it mean that they are identical as labelled graphs?  Should it mean that they are represented with identical data structures?  It is not very well known that `Graph` can have multiple different internal representations (sparse array, edge list, ect.), which are completely transparent to users.  There also seems to be some internal caching going on with certain graph computations (e.g. possibly with layouts), which again isn't exposed at all to the user.

This is not an answer, just a long comment.  I made this comment because some might read your question as a complaint—"something obviously isn't right".  But I just don't see how it could be made to work in a way that everyone would agree is correct.

Comment: "something obviously isn't right" because this is a growing part of the system and documentation does not explain it. The tutorial/ExpressionsOverview says nothing, isn't it ridiculous?