# How to represent 1 as Symbol["Integer"]

Tags: expression-construction, head

Maybe this is a boring question, but I cannot figure it out. Because every expression has a `Head`, and `Head[1]` is `Integer`, and `Head[Integer]` is `Symbol`. Therefore, `1` should somehow represented as `Symbol["Integer"][1]` or something similar. However, `Depth[1]` is one which means `1` should be presented as `Symbol["Integer..."]`, not as a expression of depth 2, such as `Symbol["Integer"][1]`.

What is correct representation of `1`?

Comment: tl;dr `Integer` and `Symbol` are special. While everything must have some head, atomic objects are effectively headless. See if `tutorial/BasicObjects` helps to understand. Also, you'll find that `Head[Symbol]` is `Symbol`, but that doesn't mean that everything in the language is `Symbol[Symbol[Symbol[...`

Comment: It's a nice question though, so I hope someone with deep understanding of the subject will point to a duplicate or provide a detailed explanation.

Comment: To answer the question of the OP, the correct and fullest representation of `1` is literally `1`. Even `ToBoxes[1]` gives `"1"`.

Comment: On second thoughts, I think you're on to something here. From the tutorial I suggested, *Atomic objects in the Wolfram Language are considered to have depth 0 and yield `True` when tested with `AtomQ`.* On the other hand, you rightly observe that `Depth[1]` is 1 although it is atomic. Perhaps, some inconsistency in the documentation.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP @Xavier Therefore, because `Integer` is an `Atom`, it is a special type of expression. Therefore, `Head` of an expression does not imply the expression has a explicit form that start with the head.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Mathematica there are *compound expressions* and *atomic expressions*.

Anything that `AtomQ` returns `True` for is atomic, and may behave in "strange" ways.  These must be considered indivisible by users, and only standard and documented ways should be used to extract information from them.

All the rest are compound expressions and have the form `head[arg1, arg2, ...]`.  Here `head` is the head of the compound expression.

Atomic expressions have "heads" too, by convention.  These do not indicate a structure.  They are used in practice to indicate the *type* of the atomic expression so we can programatically distinguish an `Integer` from a `Real`.  The fact that `Head[1]` returns `Integer` does not imply that `1` is somehow represented as `Integer[...]` because `AtomQ[1]` is `True`.

---

**Finally a warning:**

Don't be fooled by what e.g. `FullForm` might show for an atomic expressions (e.g. `FullForm[2/3]` is `Rational[2,3]` which *looks like* it has a structure: an explicit head and two arguments.  In reality it doesn't.  `AtomQ[2/3]` is `True`.  In practice atomic objects vary in how they behave when you attempt to disassemble them, but none of them work with *all* functions that would allow looking into their structure (such as pattern matching on the structure `FullForm` shows, `Part`, `Extract`, `Depth`, etc.).  When you work with some objects, you must read their documentation and only handle them in standard and documented ways. Otherwise your code might misbehave in ways you didn't expect.

Other than the most basic data types in Mathematica (`Symbol`, `String`, `Integer`, `Rational`, etc.) there are more complex atomic objects such as `SparseArray`, `Graph`, `Image`, `MeshRegion`, etc.  These are made to be atomic so that they can have a more efficient internal implementation.

Comment: This means atomic expression has a head, but they can not be parted with Part. Therefore, we can only get `1[[0]]`, but cannot get `1[[1]]`. All integers are not the same, but if you compare them part by part they are the "same".

Comment: @Kattern See my update to the post.  In short: compound expressions behave as you'd expect.  But for atomic ones: there's no rule on what you can do with them.  They're all different.

Comment: @Xavier Thanks, will edit that in an hour!

Comment: Amusingly, pattern-matching works with these two-argument atoms such as rational and complex. e.g. `MatchQ[2/3, _[_,_]]`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP This is interesting, `TreeForm[2/3]` shows only one leaf. Therefore, 2/3 should have some internal structures that can match the pattern.

Comment: @Kattern As Szabolcs explicitly mentioned, `FullForm` on atoms sometimes gives things like `Rational[2,3]`. The pattern-matcher, I believe, is a "lexicographical" matcher (if I'm using this term correctly), so it seems that it matches the structure of the `FullForm` without regard for the true structure. PS, can't emphasise the **it seems** enough. It's what it looks like, but don't take my word for it.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP you comment is right. It is in the document of `FullForm`: "Pattern matching is based on the FullForm:"

Comment: @Kattern It's not as simple as that.  This works: `Replace[1/2, h_[n_, d_] :> {h, d, n}]`.  Stuff like this also works for `SparseArray`.  For `Graph` it doesn't work at all (also atomic).  `Cases[1/2,_]` doesn't work but `Cases[rational[1,2], _]` does.  In general, what does and what doesn't work for an atomic object is unpredictable.  Also what result you get this way from an atomic object is also unpredictable because they do not *really* have the structure `FullForm` shows.  However, most atomic objects are really convertible to a compound expression for the purpose of storing ...

Comment: ... in files or sending through a MathLink connection.  This is again a different thing.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97332/12  The statement that "pattern matching is based on FullForm" only applies for compound expressions, and it's just really trying to point out that for a (compound) expression what matters is not what you see on screen, but the underlying representation (in e.g. `FullForm[a/b]`).

Comment: Can this be deduced by reading documentation around "everything is an expression"?