# How Times work in delayed rule

Tags: replacement, summation

I'm trying to understand an answer to the question: [How to do algebra on summations of variable expressions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65471/how-to-do-algebra-on-summations-of-variable-expressions/65576)
The following input:

```
reindex = s : sum[_, {i_, __}] :> (s /. i -> Unique[ToString[i]]);
unpower = s_sum^p_Integer :> Times @@ Table[s /. reindex, {p}];
test = (5*sum[x[k], {k, 1, kk}])^2;
test /. unpower

Out[4]= 25 sum[x[k3], {k3, 1, kk}] sum[x[k4], {k4, 1, kk}]
```

produces result, that differs from result produced by expressions ($25\neq625$):

```
unpowerstep1 = s_sum^p_Integer :> Table[s /. reindex, {p}];
intermediate = test /. unpowerstep1
Times @@ intermediate

Out[6]= {25 sum[x[k5], {k5, 1, kk}], 25 sum[x[k6], {k6, 1, kk}]}    
Out[7]= 625 sum[x[k5], {k5, 1, kk}] sum[x[k6], {k6, 1, kk}]
```

Also, I cannot undestand what `s_sum` mean. Does it mean, that s is any expression with head sum?

Comment: "Does it mean, that s is any expression with head sum?" Yes.

Comment: Wolfram documentation states that pattern matching is based on the FullForm, but FullForm never returns the word Integer in its output. So, I didn't know that Integer is also the head, that caused confusion when thinking about meaning of s_sum and p_Integer. OK, if s is any expression with head sum then: why intermediate variable contains value 25 located out of the sum?

Comment: @Shinrei This should answer your doubts: [Anything that AtomQ returns True for is atomic, and may behave in "strange" ways.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109642/5478)