# What's the difference between 56 and Integer[56]?

Tags: output-formatting, symbols, built-in-symbols, expression-form

I'm trying to grasp how to Wolfram Language uses symbolic expressions for everything. The concept of doing so makes sense to me, but the language doesn't behave how I predict.

I understand how writing `x + y` is *really* writing `Plus[x, y]`.

But my understanding then predicts that writing `56` is *really* writing `Integer[56]`. And that writing something like `2 + 3` is *really* writing `Plus[Integer[2], Integer[3]]`.

`FullForm` says otherwise, though. If I do `FullForm[56]` I just get back `56`. And if I do `FullForm[Integer[56]]` I get back `Integer[56]`.

`TreeForm` agrees with `FullForm`. Here is what predict I should see when doing `TreeForm[Integer[56] + 56 * 2]`:

[image: The predicted results of running TreeForm on the previously described input.]

And here's what I *actually* get:

[image: The true results of running TreeForm on the previously described input.]

So what's happening to cause these difference between my prediction and what I actually see?

**Edit:**

The answer may have something to do with "atomic objects", which are briefly discussed here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BasicObjects.html#15871

It's not very helpful, though. *Why* are these objects atomic? What is the use of having both `56` and `Integer[56]`? And why does `Head[56]` produce `Integer` if `56` is specifically supposed to be atomic--*not* breakable into any smaller pieces, like a head? `AtomQ` is a thing. But what does the Q stand for? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AtomQ.html is silent on the rationale behind the name.

**Edit 2:**

Based on answers and comments made prior to this edit, I've updated my understanding.

I think my basic problem was that I assumed that an expression passed to `FullForm` or `TreeForm` is *not* evaluated. This would be the intuitive behavior, especially for a student learning about the order of arithmetic operations.

But that behavior would also require that different functions differ on whether they choose to evaluate an expression or not, and *that* would introduce an rather arbitrary complexity to the whole enchilada. Users would need to remember which functions do or don't evaluate expressions passed as arguments. Yech.

If, however, I go with the idea that expressions are always evaluated, then it makes perfect sense that `FullForm[2 + 2]` and `FullForm[Plus[2, 2]]` give back `4`, because `2 + 2` and `Plus[2, 2]` would be evaluated before `FullForm` ever got to see them.

And so immediately wondered about how to prevent an expression from being evaluated. And `HoldForm` appeared, and now I can do `TreeForm[HoldForm[2 + 2]]` to get:

[image: The results of running TreeForm in the previously described input.]

Which is fundamentally what I expect.

*However.* It still doesn't make sense that `Head[56]` gives back `Integer`. As before, `56` is supposed to be atomic. It's obvious that it's useful to be able test *what* 56 is, but I'm having hard time coping with the idea that a thing described as atomic.. isn't. And that's a [different question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202151/why-do-atomic-objects-like-56-have-a-head-if-theyre-supposed-to-be-well-atomi).

Thanks to those who helped sort me out.

Comment: You might want to cogitate on the result of `AtomQ[56]` versus `AtomQ[Integer[56]]`.

Comment: Others that you might find interesting to ponder: Head[56] and 56[[0]].

Comment: "Q" at the end of a function signifies it returns True or False e.g. PrimeQ, PalindromeQ.

Comment: Related: [How to represent 1 as Symbol[“Integer”]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109639/9490), and [Why can't a string be formed by head String?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59671/9490).  The accepted answer to the latter is helpful for understanding these types of expressions.

Comment: `Plus` is a function that is defined somewere in the system. `Integer` is not defined, how can it evaluate to anything if it is not defined!

Comment: It seems to me that [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59674/10397) on the question linked by @  lirtosiast explains what the OP needs, so this question has been closed as a [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer[56]` has no special meaning in *Mathematica*. However, `Integer` is a symbol, so it's a perfectly valid expression by itself. `56` is a valid argument. So, `Integer[56]` is a proper expression, although it has no built-in meaning. You may, however, write patterns that match it, so you may define your own transformations that apply to it. That's how *Mathematica* works: it's an expression rewriting language. If it doesn't recognize a valid expression, it leaves it alone.

Comment: This is the solution which unstuck me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer` is not a function.

Consider this

```
a = f[b]
Head@a
```

> f

Now, if the `Head` of `a` is `f`, does it mean that `a` is the same as `f[a]`? clearly not. So, why you expect 56 to be the same as Integer[56] given that `Integer` is not a function?

Comment: The fact that `Head /@ {56, Integer[56]}` returns `{Integer, Integer}` is probably the source of some confusion.

Comment: Just two expressions sharing the same `Head`, likewise `Head /@ {a, f[a]}` returns `{f,f}`

Comment: Named "functions" in *Mathematica* are tricky things. `Sin[x]` doesn't evaluate like a function, but gets treated as a transformable symbolic expression by machinery whose rules incorporate the properties of the sine function. There is no built-in rule that does anything with `Integer[56]`.

Comment: My reasoning had gone like this: 1) Everything is a symbolic expression. 2) All symbolic expressions are composed of a head and any number of arguments. 3) Head[56] produces Integer. 4) The information that the integer is 56 must be kept somewhere. 5) That information can't be the head, since that's Integer. 6) So it must be an argument. 7) Therefore, FullForm[56] should produce Integer[56], the same way FullForm[{a, b}] produces List[a, b]. I'm now unstuck as far as this question is concerned, but I'll be making another one that focuses on atomic objects not behaving atomically.

Comment: @MadEmperorYuri You might also wonder why  `FullForm[a]` is `a` , not `Symbol[a]`