# How to test if an Audio object is file backed and extract the file path?

Tags: sound

[`Audio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Audio.html) objects can be file backed and support out of core processing.  How can I test if an `Audio` object is file backed and programmatically extract the file path?

This information is displayed, but I want to get it programmatically.

[image]

Note that `Audio` objects are atomic so `First[au]` doesn't work.  I can convert to [a non-atomic form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97332/12) in several ways, but I consider this a nasty hack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the *undocumented* function `` Audio`AudioInformation[] ``:

```
au = ExampleData[{"Audio", "Bird"}];

"ResourcePath" /. Audio`AudioInformation[au]
```

For an `Audio[]` object that is not file-backed, `None` is returned instead of the file path.

---

(Szabolcs)

This also works:

```
Audio`AudioInformation[au, "ResourcePath"]
```

Finally, you can use `` Audio`AudioStreamQ[] `` to directly query if an `Audio[]` object is file-backed:

```
Audio`AudioStreamQ[au]
   True
```

Comment: Oops, didn't see this!

Comment: There are properties which are not returned by `AudioInformation[au]`, but can be queried explicitly, e.g. `AudioInformation[au, "AudioID"]`.