# How do I replace expressions inside a Graph object?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, replacement

Say I have a `Graph` with some labels, and I want to change one of the labels. For example

```
graph = Graph[
    {1, 2, 3},
    {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1},
    VertexLabels -> {1 -> "someLabel"}
];
```

I now want to change the label from `"someLabel"` to `"someOtherLabel"`.

Naively, I would do this by simply using `ReplaceAll`: `graph /. "someLabel" -> "someOtherLabel"`.

However, this doesn't seem to work for `Graph` expressions, I guess because they are treated as atomic by Mathematica.
How can I do this? More generally, is there an easy way to convert a `Graph` object into its generating expression, so that I can modify it?

Comment: Have you looked at `SetProperty[]`?

Comment: @J.M. I was not aware of those functions. Thank you. Still, do you know if there is an easy way to directly convert the `Graph` into a "normal" (i.e. non atomic) expression?

Comment: [Carl's `Nucleus[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157198) might be what you want for that case.

Answer (score 5):

Following a suggestion in the comments, one way to do this is with `SetProperty` and `PropertyValue`, of which I was not aware:

```
replaceInVertexLabels[graph_, replacementRules_] := SetProperty[graph,
    VertexLabels -> (PropertyValue[graph, VertexLabels] /. replacementRules)
];

replaceInVertexLabels[graph, "someLabel" -> "someOtherLabel"]
```

I still find this method a bit weird, and wouldn't mind a way to directly convert into the `Graph` into a "normal" expression, but nevertheless this does the job.

Comment: As of Version 12.1, `SetProperty` has been superseded by `Annotate`.

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you for the comment. I still have v11.3, so can't test it.  Could you add an example of how `Annotate` would work here?

Comment: For version 12.1 use `Annotate` and `AnnotationValue`, e.g.,  `replaceInVertexLabels[graph_, replacementRules_] := 
  Annotate[graph, 
   VertexLabels -> (AnnotationValue[graph, VertexLabels] /. 
      replacementRules)];`

Comment: @BobHanlon SetProperty, etc. still work fine in 12.1. If they didn't, that would be a very serious compatibility break for zero benefit. As far as I can tell, these functions were simply renamed without any change in functionality.

Answer (score 2):

With [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#property-handling-and-transformations), you can simply do

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}, 
      VertexLabels -> {1 -> "foo", 2 -> "baz", 3 -> "ping", "pong"}]

IGVertexMap[ Replace[{"foo" -> "bar", "baz" -> "boo"}], VertexLabels, g]
```

`IGVertexMap[f, property, graph]` will map the function `f` to each vertex `property` value stored in `graph`.