# How to convert Graph atomic object back into unevaluated expression?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, evaluation, expression-manipulation, undocumented, conversion

For the purposes of further development of my [shortInputForm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) function, I wish to convert `Atomic` objects such as `Graph` into non-atomic *Mathematica* expressions (not the `InputForm` strings!) where `Graph` head itself would be temporarily inactivated. The following obvious method is ugly, highly inefficient, and potentially can have undesirable side-effects:

```
g = Graph[{UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[3, 1]}];

ToExpression[StringReplace[ToString[g, InputForm], "Graph" -> "Inactive[Graph]"]]
```

> [image: screenshot]

Is there a better way to "un-evaluate" a `Graph` object?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157198/9490

Comment: @JasonB. Thank you, I completely forgot about that question (and did not find it with a search).

Comment: I only found it because I remembered using the function, and it was not easy to search for.  I don’t like it when the “canonical” version of a question has a horrible title.

Comment: I forgot that I can close duplicates with a single vote. Hope the solution there is fine for you.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, it is fine. But that question is really deeply buried - very difficult to find.

Comment: @Szabolcs I just found that `Nucleus` doesn't work with `NumericArray` and `ByteArray`. Do you have an idea how to make it work?

Comment: Don't have time now, but Nucleus is based on my idea here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97332/12 You can look into that perhaps, and see if the raw solution works.

Comment: @Szabolcs No, it doesn't.

Comment: It is possible that they added proper support for NumericArray to MathLink, making NumericArrays a proper first-class atomic object, obviating the need for the compound form. There needs to be a set of "real" atomic expressions in terms of which compound expressions can be written. So not everything can have a compound form. I'm really not sure. I notice that `Rational`s can also not be made compound this way. You can also try other serialization formats such as `Compress` or WXF (though I think WXF supports NumericArray directly)

Comment: @Szabolcs The `Uncompress[Compress[expr], HoldComplete]` route also doesn't work. So the only way seems to be the good old `ToExpression[ToString[expr,InputForm],InputForm,HoldComplete]`?

Comment: I guess so. Or maybe the answer is that you should not do it. It would depend on the application.

Comment: You can special case these few atomic expressions, like NumericArray, Rational or Complex, and extract their parts using the normal API, e.g. `Numerator` / `Denominator`.

Comment: I am wondering if a Real32/Real64 NumericArray can hold NaN or Inf values (which are not otherwise representable in Mathematica). If yes, that is an argument for not having a compound form.

Comment: @Szabolcs If you are right, then probably `ToExpression[ToString[expr,InputForm],InputForm,HoldComplete]` won't return the original array in such cases, which should be considered as a bug.