# Pattern not matching BoundaryMeshRegion

Tags: pattern-matching, regions, mesh, expression-manipulation, undocumented

*Mathematica* 13.1 on Windows 10.

Can someone explain why the following does not match:

```
MatchQ[BoundaryMeshRegion[Cube[]], BoundaryMeshRegion[__]]

(* False *)
```

Comment: mesh regions are atomic, which makes them opaque to the pattern matcher. If you use `_BoundaryMeshRegion` as a pattern it will work.

Comment: does this work for you?If you  prevent evaluation of the left side, then it does match `MatchQ[Unevaluated@BoundaryMeshRegion[Cube[]], 
 BoundaryMeshRegion[___]]` gives `True`

Comment: @Jason B  Thanks a lot for the explanation. Is there a way to get the at the innards of _BoundaryMeshRegion, because "Part" does not work because it is atomic.

Comment: @Nasser - when would you want to do that? Usually the issue is that you have an evaluated object, in this case a mesh region, and you want to write a pattern to match it.

Comment: @DanielHuber - all you have are the accessor functions like `MeshCoordinates`, `MeshCells`, `MeshPrimitives`.  There are hacky methods to get at the `InputForm` but they are rarely the right way to do things.

Comment: @Nasser I want to get at the innards of BoundaryMeshRegion

Comment: @Jason B  "MeshCoordinates" works fine. I want to change the coordinates. However, how to I insert the changed coordiantes back into BoundaryMeshRegion[...]

Comment: *That* is a good question - 'what is the right way to modify an existing mesh region?'.  [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96225/9490) are the methods for accessing the innards of atoms.  Carl's nucleus function is nice

Comment: @JasonB. sometimes `Unevaluated` is needed in `MathQ`. Here is an example  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVm4q.png)  this is from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-rnezxOCA8  at time 50:57  so Tried on this example and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out in the comments, the reason of the no-match is, that `BoundaryMeshRegion` is atomic.

My ultimate goal is to change the innards of a `BoundaryMeshRegion` or any other atomic object. Toward this aim, the function [`Nucleus`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157198/280) from [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) is a big step forward.

I give here a simple example how to change a `BoundaryMeshRegion` of a `Rectangle`:

First the function [`Nucleus`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157198/280) from Carl Woll:

```
Nucleus[input_, head_ : Automatic] := 
 With[{atoms = 
    Replace[head, {Automatic :> 
       If[AtomQ[input], {Head[input]}, 
        Message[Nucleus::atom]; $Failed], h_Symbol :> {h}, 
      h : {__Symbol} :> 
       h, _ :> (Message[Nucleus::syms, head, 2]; $Failed)}]}, (If[! 
       MemberQ[Links[], $AtomLink] || LinkReadyQ[$AtomLink], 
     Quiet@LinkClose[$AtomLink];
     $AtomLink = LinkCreate[LinkMode -> Loopback]];
    LinkWrite[$AtomLink, input];
    inactiveBlock[atoms, LinkRead[$AtomLink]]) /; atoms =!= $Failed]

SetAttributes[inactiveBlock, HoldAll]
inactiveBlock[h_List, body_] := 
 Block @@ 
  Join[Apply[Set, Hold@Evaluate@Thread[{h, Inactive /@ h}], {2}], 
   Hold[body]]

Nucleus::syms = 
  "Argument `1` at position `2` is expected to be a symbol or a list \
of symbols";
Nucleus::atom = "Unable to determine atomic symbol";
```

The `BoundaryMeshRegion` of some rectangle is:

```
bmr=BoundaryMeshRegion[Rectangle[{0, 0}]]
```

[image]

and the `FullForm` of the atom:

```
nuc= Nucleus[bmr];
FullForm[nuc]
```

[image]

We may now change the coordinate of the first vertex. Note that the real number are written with a tick:

```
changed= nuc /. {0.`, 0.`} -> {0.5, 0};
```

Finally we may re-activate the changed rectangle:

```
Activate[changed]
```

[image]